Tikz heatmap, cannot put float for the rest of a line?
my issue is the following : I want to create a heatmap (for now it's only black, I'll take care of the colors after) but I cannot enter a float on the rest of a specific line even though I did before. On the 4th line, I had problems putting my 0.0 so I put 0 but the rest of the values of the line have to be integer or else : "No PDF".
Below is the code and what it gives.
\documentclass[
  tikz,
  class=scrartcl, % underlying class which is loaded by standalone
  headinclude,fontsize=11pt % options used by typearea
]{standalone}

\storeareas\standalonelayout % save the standalone layout
\recalctypearea % recalculate the typearea layout
\edef\savedtextheight{\the\textheight} % save the text height of the typearea layout
\standalonelayout % restore the standalone layout

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \foreach \y [count=\n] in {
      {2.7, 0.0, 2.2, 0.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 0.0, 2.0, 2.1},
      {0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.7, 2.6, 2.7, 2.9, 0.0, 2.5},
      {2.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2.3, 0.0, 0.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.4, 2.3, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 2.2},
      {0.0, 0.0, 2.3, 2.7, 2.0, 2.2, 2.2, 0, 0, 100, 25, 39, 20, 3},
      {3,7,3,2,12,1,0,0,0,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,7,3,2,1,36,0,0,0,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,2,3,6,0,0,45,1,1,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,3,3,5,0,0,1,23,1,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,2,3,5,0,0,1,1,78,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,2,3,5,0,0,1,1,78,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,2,3,5,0,0,1,1,78,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,2,3,5,0,0,1,1,78,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,2,3,5,0,0,1,1,78,74,25,39,20,3},
      {3,2,3,5,0,0,1,1,78,74,25,39,20,3},
    } {
      % heatmap tiles
      \foreach \x [count=\m] in \y {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xcheck}{\x}
        \ifnum\xcheck=0.0
          % Do nothing
        \else
          % \node[fill=yellow!\x!purple, minimum size=6mm, text=white] at (\m,-\n) {\x};
          \node[fill=black, minimum size=10mm, text=white] at (\m,-\n) {\footnotesize \x};
        \fi
      }
    }

  % row labels
  \foreach \a [count=\i] in {Co, Cu, Fe, Ir, Mn, Mo, Nb, Ni, Pt, Ru, Sb, Sn, Ta, Ti} {
    \node[minimum size=10mm, anchor=east] at (0,-\i) {\a};
  }

  % manually define and place column labels
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (1,-14.5) {Co};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (2,-14.5) {Cu};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (3,-14.5) {Fe};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (4,-14.5) {Ir};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (5,-14.5) {Mn};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (6,-14.5) {Mo};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (7,-14.5) {Nb};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (8,-14.5) {Ni};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (9,-14.5) {Pt};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (10,-14.5) {Ru};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (11,-14.5) {Sb};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (12,-14.5) {Sn};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (13,-14.5) {Ta};
  \node[minimum size=6mm, anchor=north] at (14,-14.5) {Ti};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


and here is what I want to put, I went step by step because I had no pdf when just copy-pasting.
{2.7, 0.0, 2.2, 0.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 0.0, 2.0, 2.1},
{0.0, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.7, 2.6, 2.7, 2.9, 0.0, 2.5},
{2.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2.3, 0.0, 0.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.4, 2.3, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 2.2},
{0.0, 0.0, 2.3, 2.7, 2.0, 2.2, 2.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2.4, 2.4, 2.6, 2.1, 2.2},
{1.9, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 2.4, 0.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 0.0, 1.8, 0.0},
{2.1, 0.0, 0.0, 2.2, 0.0, 2.4, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 0.0, 2.0, 2.1},
{2.1, 0.0, 2.2, 2.2, 1.9, 2.1, 2.4, 2.2, 2.3, 2.2, 2.3, 2.5, 0.0, 0.0},
{2.3, 0.0, 2.4, 0.0, 2.1, 2.3, 2.2, 0.0, 2.5, 2.4, 2.4, 2.6, 2.2, 2.2},
{2.3, 2.7, 2.4, 0.0, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 3.1, 2.5, 2.5, 2.7, 2.2, 2.3},
{2.3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.4, 2.1, 2.3, 2.2, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, 2.4, 2.6, 2.1, 2.2},
{2.3, 2.7, 0.0, 2.4, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.4, 0.0, 0.0, 2.2, 2.3},
{0.0, 2.9, 0.0, 2.6, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.6, 0.0, 3.3, 2.4, 2.5},
{2.0, 0.0, 2.1, 2.1, 1.8, 2.0, 0.0, 2.2, 2.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 1.5, 0.0},
{2.1, 2.5, 2.2, 2.2, 0.0, 2.1, 0.0, 2.2, 2.3, 2.2, 2.3, 2.5, 0.0, 1.7},


Use \ifnum only for integers. If you want to deal with floating point numbers, you can e.g. use pgf: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724021/36296

Thanks to samcarter :
  % heatmap tiles
  \foreach \x [count=\m] in \y {
    \pgfmathparse{\x} % Parse the value
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xvalue}{\pgfmathresult} % Store the result in a variable
    \ifdim\xvalue pt=0pt
      % Do nothing
    \else
      % \node[fill=yellow!\x!purple, minimum size=6mm, text=white] at (\m,-\n) {\x};
      \node[fill=black, minimum size=10mm, text=white] at (\m,-\n) {\footnotesize \xvalue};
    \fi
  }
}

